# Creating a serial object casing problems with multiprocessing module

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pyserial

I am trying to use multiprocessing module along with reading data from serial port (Please also refer to my earlier post [Multiprocessing code bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136805/multiprocessing-code-bug)). I verified it by systematically commenting out the code. The code runs fine but as soon as a serial object is initialized, the multiprocessing doesn't produce any results. Can some one please tell what can be going wrong here? Has anyone faced this thing before? Or I am doing something wrong? Please advice